# Bulk Insert пропускается вторая строка

Tags: insert, sql-server, sql

Имеется входной текстовый файл (выгрузка из CRM). В теле 55 столбцов (разделённых табуляром), первая строка с заголовком имеет 54 столбца. По идеи код

```
BULK INSERT dbo.dbname
FROM 'C:\all_Crm\2014\august\data_dbname.txt'
WITH 
(
    CODEPAGE = '1251',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    MAXERRORS = 10,
);
```

Должен добавлять все строки начиная со второй, однако добавляется с третей, если удалить первую строку с поехавшей шапкой и заменить `FIRSTROW = 1`, то всё добавляется верно.
Т.е. `FIRSTROW` срабатывает не на окончание строки, а на 55 столбцов (54 + 1 из следующий) и окончание строки (т.е. уже следующей строки). Удалять строку с шапкой предворительно не представляется возможным (размер файла 500мб-2,5Гб). Как можно заставить работать верно?

Comment: А в хэлпе по bulk insert что написано?

Comment: Про данную ситуацию - ничего (MSDN в принципе хреновый хелп)

Comment: Нормальный в MSDN хелп: Атрибут FIRSTROW не предназначен для пропуска заголовков столбцов. Пропуск заголовков не поддерживается инструкцией BULK INSERT. При пропуске строк компонент Компонент SQL Server Database Engine выполняет поиск только в признаках конца поля и не проверяет данные в полях пропущенных строк. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx. Вы пытаетесь MS SQL "скормить" некорректные данные - и ждете, что они будут корректно обработаны.

Comment: Кстати, насчет удаления строки. А не думали динамически формировать запрос на bulk insert? Прочитали строку заголовка, посмотрели количество \t, если оно совпадает с требуемым - берем firstrow=2, если меньше - берем firstrow=1? и файл перелопачивать не надо будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.

А пробовали воспользоваться FORMATFILE?
И уже в файле форматирования указать, что 55я колонка не описана в строке-заголовке (см. здесь: [Создание файла форматирования (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191516.aspx)).

> FORMATFILE ='format_file_path'
>   Указывает полный путь к файлу форматирования. Этот файл форматирования содержит описание файла данных — сведения, полученные путем применения программы bcp к той же таблице или представлению. И предназначен для случаев, когда:
>
> - файл данных содержит больше или меньше столбцов, чем таблица или представление;
> - столбцы расположены в другом порядке;
> - отличаются разделители столбцов;
> - имеются какие-либо другие изменения в формате данных. Файлы
>     форматирования обычно создаются с помощью программы bcp и затем при
>     необходимости изменяются в текстовом редакторе. Дополнительные
>     сведения см. в разделе Программа bcp.